# Defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget, embedio

Hi im trying to add EmbedIO DLL to a Unity C# project, i have added EmbedIO.dll and Swan.Lite.dll to my project just adding them with NuGet and also try with placing the .DLL in the assets directory, but i keep getting this error.

All the DLL im using are for netstandar2.0.

But im keep getting this error:

Error CS0012: The type 'ConfiguredObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Swan.Lite, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30c707c872729fff'. (CS0012)

My package.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EmbedIO" version="3.4.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unosquare.Swan.Lite" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

And my Assembly-CsSharp.csproj
looks like this: `https://pastebin.com/E6raLbYe`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

You can use the 3.0.0 version of "Unosquare.Swan.Lite".

It also worked normally in a Unity environment.